# Spring AOP pointcut not applying to abstract methods

Tags: java, spring, aop, pointcut

I have the following pointcut:

```
@Before(value="execution(* datasync.polling.Poller+.*(..))")
public void beforePoll() {
    logger.info("DOING THIS");
}
```

And the following abstract class:

```
package datasync.polling;
import datasync.principle;

public abstract class Poller<P extends Principle> {
    protected P principle;

    public Poller(P principle) {
        this.principle = principle;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Poller for " + principle.toString();
    }

    public abstract P doPoll();
}
```

My pointcut only applies when I call Poller.toString(), not Poller.doPoll().  I would expect it to apply to any method that takes any number of arguments within the Poller class or it's subclasses.  Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Likely a dot is missing in the expression

```
@Before(value="execution(* datasync.polling.Poller+.*(..))")
@Before(value="execution(* datasync.polling.Poller+..*(..))")
                                                   ^
```